# Scrape PokeDex and display in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, tkinter, selenium

Hi I am new here and I just completed my first working version of a pokedex app with a GUI using tkinter. I used selenium to scrape the data from pokemondb.net, and then used pandas to clean up the dataset then finished it up with a tkinter GUI. The project is still in early stages and can be improved in the front and backend. However, I do not have a specific question. I simply would like to receive feedback and an honest opinion of the project so far in the development process. I would be happy for any suggestions on improving the user interface also, and making it more aesthetically appealing as well. I have the entire project posted on github, however I am not sure if posting the link would be allowed here, so instead I'll post the code here.

```
#pokedex.py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt


file_path = 'drivers/chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(file_path) # assign the driver path to variable

driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all'})

driver.minimize_window() # minimize window

data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#pokedex"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")

df  = pd.read_html(data)

df = df[0]

driver.close()  # close driver, end session

columns = ['id', 'name', 'type', 'total', 'hp', 'attack', 'defense', 'special-attack', 'special-defense', 'speed'] # column names (labels) for dataset


df.set_index("#", inplace=True) # set the id column to be the index

os.makedirs('C:/Users/Salah/Documents/apps/pokedex-app/datasets', exist_ok=True) # create new folder in project directory to store dataset  

df.to_csv("datasets/pokedex.csv", index=False) # converts dataset to csv file

df = pd.read_csv('datasets/pokedex.csv') # read and save file and check the first 5 entries

df.head()


for name in df.Name:
    if name.__contains__('Mega '):
        mega_id = df.index[df['Name'] == name].tolist()
        #print(mega_id)
        df.Name[mega_id] = name.split(' ', 1)[1]

poke_list = list(df.Name[:])

poke_list

df.head(10)
```

````
#gui.py
from os import times
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from turtle import color, width
from xmlrpc.client import loads
from pokedex import *


#window
window = tk.Tk()  #main

window.title('Universal Pokedex')
window.configure(background="red")
window.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")

bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/pokedex.gif")

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, height=700, width=800)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(window, bg='red')
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
#window


def validate_text():
    global entry
    string = entry.get()
    #label_2.configure(text=string)
    string = string.title() # capitalize first letter of entry to match database

    if string not in poke_list:   # ensure the user is typing in valid input, if not create a validation loop by reiterating user to give valid pokemon name or id.
        label_2.configure(text="That pokemon was not found, please try again: ") # validation look/error trap
    string = string.title()

    if string in poke_list:
        print("Searching for {} ... ".format(string))
        print("{} Found!".format(string))
        poke_stats = df.loc[df['Name'] == string] # return pokemon stats to user if successfully located
        label_2.configure(text=poke_stats)



#phsyical properties
label_1 = tk.Label(window, text="Welcome to the Universal Pokedex! This program contains the statistics of all the pokemon stored in the official Pokemon Database. \n Begin by entering a pokemon name below.", bg='red', font=("Cambria", 25))
label_1.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)

label_2 = tk.Label(window, text="Enter a pokemon name to see a list of its stats: ", bg='#5CB3FF', font=("Courier", 20))
label_2.place(relx=0, rely=0.78, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)

img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/johto-starters.gif"))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/pokeball.gif"))

label_3 = tk.Label(window, bg='red', image=img1) # This label will contain the entered pokemon's image
label_3.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.50, relheight=0.50)

label_4 = tk.Label(window, bg='white', image=img2)
label_4.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.3)

label_5 = tk.Label(window, bg='white', image=img2)
label_5.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.3)

entry = tk.Entry(window, bg='white')
entry.place(relx=0.42, rely=0.89, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.04)

button = tk.Button(window, text="Search", command=validate_text, bg='grey')
button.place(relx=0.42, rely=0.94, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.05)
#physical properties





#widgets

#widgets

window.mainloop()  #mainloop

```
````

Comment: Have you read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263671/25834 ?

Comment: With a grain of salt, because I believe your use of Pandas `read_html` to be better than the approach in that question.

Comment: No I haven't read that until now. And do you think the code could use some work? Also that was a little advice I received on stack overflow, but I do see how he could have used it better in that example.

Comment: Yes, it could use work; I'm writing up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is not necessary for this project so don't use it. You can go direct to `requests`. This website doesn't have an API but others do; you should prefer them instead. Even better, you should have an offline database embedded in your program since it never changes. Perhaps that's why you `read_csv`; this would be more useful if you first check for the existence of a CSV and only scrape in the application if it doesn't exist.

These:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
```

aren't needed, so delete them. A decent IDE will show you which imports are unneeded.

Move your global code into functions and/or classes.

There isn't much point in redefining your column names - the defaults as scraped from Pandas are actually nicer for presentation purposes.

Don't use `for` loops in Pandas. Your string operation is simple and vectorisable. Don't cast to a list.

Your colours make my eyes bleed. Call me boring, but it's rarely justifiable to override colours and fonts.

Your layout can be simplified by use of `grid` calls.

You don't need a button if you search whenever the user updates their search term in the entry box.

You should make better use of tk `StringVar` to decouple your data from your UI.

Future improvements could include calling into a fuzzy-matching library to do inexact string search, and displaying your search results in multiple rows in a real tkinter TreeView instead of dumping them to a string.

### Suggested

Covering some of the above,

```py
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
from typing import Optional

import pandas as pd
import requests


def load_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    print('Retrieving data...')

    with requests.get(
        'https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all',
        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},
    ) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        df, = pd.read_html(
            io=response.text, flavor='bs4', index_col='#',
        )

    df['SearchKey'] = df.Name.str.lower()
    df[['Name', 'Mega']] = df.Name.str.split(' Mega ', n=1, expand=True)
    return df


class GUI:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title('Universal Pokedex')
        self.run = window.mainloop
        frame = tk.Frame(window)
        frame.pack()

        tk.Label(
            frame,
            text='Welcome to the Universal Pokedex! This program contains the '
            'statistics of all the pokemon stored in the official Pokemon '
            'Database.\n'
            'Begin by entering a pokemon name below.',
            justify='left', wraplength=200,
        ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        tk.Label(
            frame, text='Pokemon name: ',
        ).grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.search_term = tk.StringVar(frame, name='search_term')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(
            frame, textvariable=self.search_term, state='disabled',
        )
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.result = tk.StringVar(frame, name='result', value='Loading...')
        tk.Label(
            frame, textvariable=self.result,
        ).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.data: Optional[pd.DataFrame] = None

    def set_data(self, data: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self.data = data
        self.result.set('')
        self.entry.configure(state='normal')
        self.search_term.trace_add('write', self.search)

    def search(self, name: str, _, mode: str) -> None:
        term = self.search_term.get().lower()
        if term:
            predicate = self.data.SearchKey.str.contains(term)
            matches = self.data[predicate].iloc[:1]
            if len(matches):
                first = matches.iloc[0, :]
                self.result.set(str(first))
                return
        self.result.set('')


def main() -> None:
    gui = GUI()

    def fetch_data() -> None:
        data = load_data()
        gui.set_data(data)

    data_thread = Thread(target=fetch_data)
    data_thread.start()

    gui.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: screencapture, squirtle]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was sure there would be many flaws that could be detected from an objective eye, so I thank you for the constructive criticism, and will work toward improvements

Comment: by the way, just curious about the offline database you mentioned. Are you refer to using a sql database? Would I insert the pokemon data into the db by using an api on another website that has one like you said?

Comment: "Offline database" can be as simple as a static CSV file shipped with your application. The application probably doesn't call for more than that.